# Android :: Not getting usb information from "adb devices -l"

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I want to know the exact USB port on which my Android device is connected. I read about the "adb device -l" command here (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) and saw that the port information can be seen as below:

```
0a388e93 device **usb:1-1** product:razor model:Nexus_7 device:flo
```

However I am not getting the USB Port information in my Windows 10 Laptop. However this information is available in Ubuntu 18.04 and Mac.

I also installed the Android Studio on my Windows 10 laptop and further installed the Google USB Drivers. However the USB Port information was still not available.

Answer (score 0):

on windows adb devices - l will not give port info , u can only see it while executing in linux system ,
Alternatively if you want to see which port your USB device is connected to you can follow the below steps
1. Open Device Manager:
Click: Start > Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Device Manager (under "Devices and Printers"
2. In the Device Manager list, look in Ports